Current in long thin superconducting loop moved into external $B$ field
This is a question of my own making to better understand induction and superconductors (so there's a better than even chance it might be incorrectly posed). Say you have a long, thin, superconducting rectangular loop. It has two very long sides of length $L$, and two short sides of length $W$, where $L>>W$ (I'm posing this geometry only because it makes the integrals simpler I think.) Initially there is no magnetic field and no current in the loop. Then an external magnetic field of magnitude $B_{ext}$ is turned on, oriented normal to the plane of the loop.
If I understand the behavior of superconductors and induction properly, this means that a current will be induced in the rectangular loop such that the magnetic flux through the loop will remain the same as it was a moment ago (IE zero magnetic flux). Is that correct?
If so, what would the current be?
Here's my attempt at solving the problem:
First I need to find the magnetic field within the loop due to some current, $I$. Given that $L>>W$, the magnetic field from the short end pieces will be negligible over most of the loop, and we can simplify it to be the magnetic field due to two infinite wires with equal current running in opposite directions. I'll locate one wire at $x=0$ and the other at $x=W$. The magnetic field between the two wires is then simply the addition of magnetic fields from two infinite wires:
$$
B(x)=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2 \pi x}+
\frac{\mu_0 I }{2 \pi (W-x)}
=k \big(\frac 1 x+\frac 1 {W-x}\big)
$$
where $k=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2 \pi}$
To find the magnetic flux through the loop due to the loop's own current then, I would just integrate B over the loop area:
$\phi=L k  \int_0^W\big(\frac 1 x + 
\frac 1 {W-x}\big) dx$
But this integral doesn't converge at $x=0$ and $W$. It would seem that ANY loop current produces infinite magnetic flux through the loop due to the divergent magnetic field approaching each of the wires.
What am I missing?

Upon further reflection, I think I'm introducing unphysical infinities by assuming infinitely thin wires. I believe the skin effect will make the current flow on the outer boundaries of the wires. So maybe rather than integrate $x$ from 0 to $W$, I should integrate from $r_{wire}$ to $W-r_{wire}$. If that's correct, then current in the loop will be greater the thicker the wires are (up to $r_{wire}=W/2$.)
In that case the flux through the loop due to current $I$ would be
$$
\phi_{loop}=2 L k \log((W-r_{wire})/r_{wire}).
$$
The magnetic flux from the external field would simply be
$$
\phi_{ext}=L W B_{ext}.
$$
Setting those magnetic fluxes equal and solving for $I$:
$$
I=\frac{\pi W B_{ext}}{\mu_0 \log((W-r_{wire})/r_{wire})}
$$
